# Is it possible to copy and paste my extent report to local drive?

Tags: java, selenium, maven

I want to copy extent report and paste into my local drive using Selenium/Java/Maven
I tried with FileInputSteam , nothing worked
Can someone help me on this, Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible. This is a multi step process, but if you break it down into individual parts and search for help on each part individually then you will find hundreds of answers online. If you want help on stack overflow then you need to focus on only one issue. Hint: Start by first working out how to load a page with Selenium, then how to retrieve content or a file with Selenium.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the question? When you say you need to copy, Is this from somewhere else? Or within the same local computer? Where do you have this extent report file?

Answer (score 0):

Import the following dependency in your project

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can copy the file from one directory to another.

```
 String currentDirectory=System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File source = new File(currentDirectory+"\\yourextendreport.html");
    File dest = new File("D:\\test\\test2\\yourextendreport.html");
    try {
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you want to copy the folder then use **copyDirectory**

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);
```

Hope this will solve your issues